# How to pass Typescript Immutable JS type as function argument

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

How to pass an object of immutable type to a function as an argument

```
interface ImmutableObject<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K],
  set<S>(o: S): Immutable<T & S>,
  "value1": string,
}

function(values: ImmutableObject) {
//.. doo stuff
}
```

I'm getting an error

> 'ImmutableObject' requires 1 type argument(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImmutableObject` is a generic interface. The actual data of the object is determined by the `T` parameter. You need to specify the `T` argument to the immutable object

```
interface ImmutableObject<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K],
  set<S>(o: S): Immutable<T & S>,
}

function foo(values: ImmutableObject<{ value1: string }>) {
  values.get('value1')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your function pass through type parameter of immutable object.

```
function <T>(values: ImmutableObject<T>) {
//.. doo stuff
}
```